# How Regularity of $X$ implies $\mathcal {A}$ covers $X$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, separation-axioms, index-notation, paracompactness

[image]

[Reference:Munkres Topology $2nd$ edition]

$X$ is PARACOMPACT+ $X$ is HAUSDORFF$\implies $ $X$ is NORMAL$\implies $ $X$ is Regular.

I'm not getting

> (1)How  does "Regularity of X implies that $\mathcal {A}$ covers X"?
>
> (2) What is the meaning of the phrase "indexing a set bijectively"?

Please help me answering the above questions,any kind of suggestion/hint will be greatly appreciated

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathscr A$ covers $X$:

Let $x \in X$. There exist $\alpha \in J$ such that $x \in U_\alpha$. By regularity there exists an open $A \subset X$ such that $x \in A$ and $\overline A \subset U_\alpha$. Clearly $A \in \mathscr A$.

Indexing $\mathscr B$ bijectively:

This means that we take any bijection $b : K \to \mathscr B$ from a set $K$ to $\mathscr B$. This "choice step" is not really needed. You can take $K = \mathscr B$ and $b = id$.

Comment: :We've  already assumed the existence of $\mathcal {A}$,which contains open sets $A,$ then why we are using Regularity for picking the open sets?also how $A\in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @P.Styles Yes, $\mathscr A$ is a well-defined collection of open sets. But theoretically its only member could be the empty set. The issue is to show that each $x \in X$ is contained in some element of $\mathscr A$. This step requires regularity. Read again my answer.

Comment: @P.Styles $\mathcal{A}=\{O \in \mathcal{T}_X\mid \exists \alpha \in A: \overline{O} \subseteq U_\alpha\}$ is a valid definition of a set. So $\mathcal{A}$ **exists** if you believe the ZF axioms. Its existence is not the issue, it being a *cover* is.